# Emojis in html email are rendered incorrectly and hidden in preview text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, unicode, emoji

I'm having a hard time adding emojis to my marketing emails on a Wordpress/ WooCommerce website. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Adding them as hex code e.g. &#x1F917
2. Adding them directly in the source code e.g.
3. A combination of both methods

The first method works pretty good and the emojis are displayed correctly in the body. However the emojis turn into Chinese characters in the preview text for some devices (iOS for instance).

The second method also only works partly. This turns the emojis into "Twitter style" emojis: they don't look like the native Apple emojis on Apple devices but like the "Twtr" ones from [this list](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). Also they're completely hidden in the preview text.

If I combine both methods however the emojis (and all other emojis in the email) are displayed correctly as Apple style emojis in the body and the preview text. I guess this might also be the case on other mail clients (Gmail, Outlook etc.) so I'd be happy to fix this.

Ideally I'd stick to method #2 there just needs to be a trick to make sure they're displayed correctly and not in the Twitter style/ hidden in the preview.

```
// Method 1:
Hi '.$firstname.' &#x1F917;

// Method 2:
Hi '.$firstname.' 

// Method 3:
Hi '.$firstname.' &#x1F917;
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that your HTML has a UTF-8 meta header in it?

Comment: Yes as part of the headers parameter in the wp_mail function "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" and meta tag in the <head> of the email <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />